# Java: How to efficiently create multiple nested zip files?

Tags: java, multithreading, zip

I am trying to create several zip files in a multi-threaded environment (actually I tried to write about 400 zip files using an FixedThreadPool ExecutorService serving 16 threads). Each of these zip files may contain thousands of other zip files.

Unfortunately after about two minutes my java process (jdk1.8.0_60_x64 on Windows 64bit) seems to end up in a memory leak. While the heap (according to Java Mission Control) only uses about 1 GB (actually between 500 MB and 1 GB), the java process in total uses about 40 GB of machine memory (seems to be a lot of native memory used). This number keeps increasing and after another while the process/my system practically stops working (I do not have that much memory).

After some research I found out it is possible to simulate the behavior using a rather small main method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
      new Thread(Integer.toString(k)) {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            long bytes = 0;
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getName() + ".tmp"))));
            zos.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);
            Random rand = new SecureRandom();
            for (int i = 0; i < 65535; i++) {
              zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("" + i));
              ZipOutputStream inner = new ZipOutputStream(zos);
              for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                byte[] b = new byte[512];
                bytes += b.length;
                rand.nextBytes(b);
                inner.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("" + j));
                inner.write(b);
                inner.closeEntry();
              }
              inner.finish();
              inner.flush();
              zos.closeEntry();
              zos.flush();
              if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                System.err.println(getName() + ": " + i + " (" + bytes + ") bytes");
              }
            }
            zos.flush();
            zos.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }.start();
    }
  }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Probably.

- Is it a bad idea to use I/O operations in these many threads? I'm really not sure about it (actually I would like to gain performance, not loose performance). But on the other side, if I leave out all the zip stuff and just write on the FileOutputStream in even more threads no such problems occur. Do the zip entries overhead increase the size that much?
- Is there anything wrong with the usage of my *inner* ZipOutputStream? As far as I understand I must not call close() for this class as it would close the outer stream named *zos* as well. Instead I am calling *finish()*.